# Nested global/static std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, initializer-list

According to the standard (since C++11):

> The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary.

Suppose I want to declare nested std::initializer_list in such way:

```
struct A {
    int                         a;
    std::initializer_list<int>  aa;
};

std::initializer_list<A> TestInitList()
{
    static std::initializer_list<A> aaa = 
    {
         {10, {1,2,3}}, {11, {4,5,6}}
    };
    return aaa;
}
```

I am expecting the lifetime of nested initializer_list members extending same way as all others.
But when debugging such construction in VC 2019, I encountered damage of nested underling arrays `aa`. It happened accidently for some members, while others remained untouched. After this incident I am very frustrated, because of I cannot trust to such constructions anymore.

Do I mistake in the standard understanding in this subject?

Comment: Did you encounter that error after the function returns? The lifetime extension works like it does with references. What would happen if we returned  `A const&` bound to a temporary?

Comment: Of course, the problem is observed after the functions returns. I tried using reference, as you suggest, it hasn't any impact. I see the same problem.

Comment: My point was that a dangling reference is a dangling reference. Not sure how static references work with lifetime extension, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

After revising all nested initialized lists in my program, as a result, in practice, it is clearly seen that all init lists of the first nesting level are preserved,
and the 2nd, 3rd ones are destroyed. To get rid of the problem, all init lists of the 2nd, 3rd level must be assigned to named variables, and then they automatically become lists of the 1st level.